# Best way to do a query with timezone

Tags: mysql

I have user from different timezone and I need to improve one of my query:

```
 WHERE DATE_ADD(pa.inspection_date, INTERVAL -39600 SECOND) >= Date( '2020-05-05')
     AND DATE_ADD(ai.inspection_completed_date, INTERVAL -39600 SECOND) <= DATE( 
           '2020-05-06') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Currently, this query is very slow ( 5 minutes) because I think the `Date_add` broke(ignore) my index on `inspection_date` field. If I remove `Date_add` I got 0.2 second result.

All my time on my database are in UTC. So I would like to know, how can I perform a mysql query with the user timezone and let's mysql keep my index.

User can choose the date they they want for my example, they choose the start and the end date

Comment: you can convert paramter date to UTC from application and modify this query.

Comment: post your table schema

Comment: Please post SHOW CREATE TABLE for pa.tablename; and ai.tablename;

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
WHERE pa.inspection_date >= (DATE('2020-05-05') + INTERVAL 11 HOUR)
  AND ai.inspection_completed_date <= DATE('2020-05-06') + INTERVAL 35 HOUR
```

And check if both columns `pa.inspection_date` and `ai.inspection_completed_date` are indexed.